# What is the best way to save an NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, serialization, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, custom-object

I have a custom object called Occasion defined as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Occasion : NSObject {

NSString *_title;
NSDate *_date;
NSString *_imagePath;    

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imagePath;
```

Now I have an NSMutableArray of Occasions which I want to save to NSUserDefaults. I know it's not possible in a straight forward fashion so I'm wondering which is the easiest way to do that? If serialization is the answer, then how? Because I read the docs but couldn't understand the way it works fully.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use something like `NSKeyedArchiver` to serialize the array to an `NSData`, save it to the `NSUserDefaults` and then use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to deserialize it later:

```
NSData *serialized = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serialized forKey:@"myKey"];

//...

NSData *serialized = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"];
NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:serialized];
```

You will need to implement the `NSCoding` protocol in your `Occasion` class and correctly save the various properties to make this work correctly. For more information see the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html). It shouldn't be more than a few lines of code to do this. Something like:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:coder];

    [coder encodeObject:_title forKey:@"_title"];
    [coder encodeObject:_date forKey:@"_date"];
    [coder encodeObject:_imagePath forKey:@"_imagePath"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

    _title = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"_title"] retain];
    _date = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"_date"] retain];
    _imagePath = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"_imagePath"] retain];

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The idea is clear to me now. One last question: for the step (NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:serialized];) would give me an NSArray while my original array is an NSMutableArray. So should I use something like [copy mutable]?

Comment: If it gives you back a standard `NSArray` then use `[array mutableCopy]` to get a mutable version.

Answer (score 4):

`NSUserDefaults` is intended for user preferences, not storing application data. Use [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) or serialize the objects into the documents directory. You'll need to have your class implement the `NSCoding` protocol for it to work.

1) Implement `NSCoding` in `Occasion.h`

```
@interface Occasion : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

2) Implement the protocol in `Occasion.m`

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.title = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
        self.date = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"date"];
        self.imagePath = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"imagePath"];

    }            
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {

    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:date forKey:@"date"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:imagePath forKey:@"imagePath"];
}
```

3) Archive the data to a file in documents directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path= [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@“occasions”];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:occasions toFile:path];
```

4) To unarchive...

```
NSMutableArray *occasions = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. My other question is: I already have 2 methods in the Occasion object called:(                            - (id)init  AND
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
             date:(NSDate *)date
            imagePath:(NSString *)imagePath )                                                       Now should I cancel these 2 methods and use initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder instead whenever I want make new instances of Occasion?

Comment: No, when you want to create objects use still use the init or initWithTitle:date:imagePath. The coder methods are only for serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `NSCoding` in `Occasion`.

You then use `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray]` to create an `NSData` object from the array. You can put this into user defaults.