# ReConvert NSString to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsarray

I have converted an NSArray to NSString using below code
Suppose i have an array with some data in it.

```
NSString *sample=[array description];
NSLog(@"%@",sample);
```

which prints:

```
 (
    {
    URL = "1a516af1a1c6020260a876231955e576202bbe03.jpg##37911944cc1ea8fd132ee9421a7b3af326afcc19.jpg";
    userId = 0;
    wallpaperId = 31;
  },
    {
    URL = "a9356863fa43bc3439487198283321622f88e31f.jpg##f09c743ebdc26bb9f98655310a0529b65a472428.jpg";
    userId = 0;
    wallpaperId = 30;
    }
)
```

It looks like array but it is actually a string.
Now I am wondering, how can I reconvert back to NSArray?
Help appreciated.

And please this not a duplicate question, I couldn't found the same anywhere on SO.

Comment: do you need explicitly a `NSString`? Because if the purpose is to serialize the content of the array to be able to deserialize it later then using an `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver` could be a better solution. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743450/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-an-nsmutablearray-to-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Generally, `description` is not reversible. Use an archiver for serialization and un-archiver for deserialization.

Comment: Yep, use JSON or the archiver stuff.  Don't use `description` except for debugging messages.

Comment: actually i need to save that array to DB in a single field thats why i am converting it to string to save it in DB and while fetching i will reconvert it back to NSArray

Comment: @Jack i think you are right, i will try your way too. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rely on the results of `description` as it is not a *convert to string* operator, but merely a debugging aid.  There is nothing to stop it changing between O/S releases and there is no equivalent `fromDescription` method.

The conventional way of serializing an Objective-C collection to and from a string is to use [JSON](http://json.org/), so look at the  [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Comment: I was wondering whether i should do this way or not but i think its a good idea to convert an array to JSON and then its easy to convert it back to array. +1

Answer (score -1):

the

```
NSString componentsseparatedbystring
```

method will return an array of components separated by a string